# Need to grep the word right next to or below a pattern

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

I have a file with the following lines in i:

```
    .......... FROM ABCD_EXT
    .......... FROM HEG_EXT1 
.......... from
           xyz_EXT
.......... FROM abd_EXT2 
..........where QWT_EXT.SID=POI_EXT.GET
..........where QWT_EXT.SID=POI_GET.END_EXT
```

I need to grep only those words that are right next to, or below the "FROM" (case insensitive) and that ends in _EXT.

ie., expected output is:

```
ABCD_EXT 
xyz_EXT
```

EDIT: Yeah, I need to grep the next word after 'from', no matter whether it occurs on the same line or the following line.

I tried with this and it gets me the first part (same line) correctly:

```
grep _EXT rt.sql |grep -i from|sed -e 's/_EXT/_EXT /g'|awk '{print $NF}'|grep _EXT
```

Getting the word from the line below is the issue.

Comment: So, what you want to say is: You need to grep the next word after 'from', no matter whether it occurs on the same line or the following line? Please edit your post to clarify, and also include what you already tried and where you faced problems. That way you can avoid getting answers that you already know won't work.

Comment: Those dots really are dots in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -Mo1 '(?<!\S)(?i:from)\s+(\S*_EXT)(?!\S)' < rt.sql
```

- `-M` for the `M`ultiline mode
- `-o1` to `o`utput what is matched by the `1`<sup>st</sup> capture group.
- `\s` matches a whitespace character (includes space, tab, CR and LF at least), `\S` matches a non-whitespace character.
- `x+`: matches 1 or more `x`s
- `x*`: matches 0 or more `x`s.
- `(?i:from)`: `from`, case insensitively same as `[fF][rR][oO][mM]`.
- `(?<!\S)`: negative look-behind for a non-whitespace, or IOW *provided what's before is not a non-whitespace* (so is either a whitespace or the start of the subject).
- `(?!\S)`: same but look-ahead instead of behind.  If it's SQL, you may want to allow `;` as well though with `(?![^\s;])`

If you don't have `pcregrep`, you can use `perl` instead (the first `p` in `pcregrep`), and slurp the whole file in with `-0777`:

```
perl -l -0777 -ne 'print for /(?<!\S)(?i:from)\s+(\S*EXT)(?!\S)/g' < rt.sql
```

Or with GNU `grep` if built with PCRE support (which adds the `-P` option to match using perl-like regexps):

```
grep -zPo '(?<!\S)(?i:from)\s+\K\S*EXT(?!\S)' < rt.sql | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Since GNU `grep` doesn't support `-o<n>` to output what was matched by the `n`<sup>th</sup> capture group, we instead use `-o` to output the entirety of what was matched, but use `\K` to tell the matcher what to `K`eep as the match.

With `-z` we work on NUL-delimited records instead of lines, so assuming the input doesn't contain NULs which should be the case for SQL and text in general, that will only be one record making up the full contents of the file like in perl's slurp-mode above. The output record separator will also be NUL though, so we need to `tr`ansliterate those to newlines to have each match on separate lines.

Comment: The grep solution worked like a charm! Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -En 'N;s/.*from( ([^_]*_ext\>)[^\n]*\n.*|\n.* ([[:alpha:]]+_ext\>))/\2\3/Ip' input_file
ABCD_EXT
xyz_EXT
```

Comment: This one worked on some files but failed on others. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your example data into `datafile`:

```
> awk -v printfirst=0 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1}
                       {if (printfirst == 1) {
                           print $1; printfirst=0; next
                                             }
                       } 
                       {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                           if ($i ~ /^from$/) {
                               if (i == NF) {printfirst=1} 
                               else if ($(i+1) ~ /_EXT$/) {print $(i+1)}
                           }
                       }' datafile

ABCD_EXT
xyz_EXT
> _
```

There are several ways of doing this with `awk` (here the GNU version of Awk). I picked that one for expediency and to avoid parsing your input file twice.

- `-v` flag to pass variable into Awk. Initiate variable `printfirst` to 0,
- `BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1}` make Awk search patterns case insensitive
- 1st `{}` block: conditioanlly print first Awk field, i.e. `$1` and jump to `next` record
- 2nd `{}` block: for the parsed record, try to match each field to `from` in a case insensitive way.

  - If no match: do nothing.
  - If match:

    - if matched field is last in record set Awk internal variable `printfirst` to 1 and go to next record
    - if matched field is not last field in record, print next field in record.

Comment: The `/EXT$/` will also end up being matched case insensitively.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: yes that's correct. Let's see whether OP considers that a good thing or a deal breaker.

Comment: Note that it outputs `pretext` on a `select fromage, pretext from excuses;` input.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: that should work now.